# Adding quotes in notepad++ for a particular format

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, i have the below data which needs to be formatted to add double quotes for data with price values. they all have $ symbol and have . followed by 2 digits.

Below is the data,

abc,dec,$123,34.00,abc abc,dec,$123,34,56.00,abc

Expected:

abc,dec,"$123,34.00",abc abc,dec,"$123,34,56.00",abc

I tried some of the commands such as (.+) and then using '\r' to replace with " but this was giving me all the rows. I couldn't find specific to the pattern $ followed by .

Can you please help with it?

Comment: Sorry, that question was closed and hence posted an other one. For your query, $123456,789,00,12,$1.1234,abc,456,789 will not have any quotes. My problem was price values had comma hence, had to enclose them in quotes so that it will be treated as single value. Price values always start with $ and ends with .00 Eg: $123,345.00 should be enclosed in quotes like "$123,345.00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the digits and replace with the whole match surrounded by double quotes

**Find what**

```
\$\d+(?:,\d+)*\.\d{2}\b
```

**Replace with**

```
"$&"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NNb1eR/1)

[image]

Comment: As i had to include the .00 at the end too, i tried out this regex based on yours - \$\d+,\d+\b\.\d+ and seem to be working.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2616662 Yes, I have updated it to match 2 digits after the dot.

Comment: Just saw ur edit. Your answer is working for data with multiple commas as well! Thanks a lot :)